# PowerShell alias is not seeing parameters during tab completion

Tags: powershell, scope, alias, tab-completion

I am using a function that can do some change directory functionality and then redirect / re-alias `cd` to that function.

```
function go ($jumpto, [switch]$DisableAliasCD, [switch]$ResetGoHash, [switch]$ResetCDHistory) {
    <stuff>
}

Set-Alias cc go
if (Test-Path Alias:cd) { Remove-Item -Path Alias:cd }    # Remove the default:   cd -> Set-Location
# Remove-Alias was not added until PS v6 so have to use Remove-Item with the Alias PSProvider
Set-Alias cd go -Option AllScope
```

Checking the syntax of each of `go`, `cc`, `cd`

```
get-command go -syntax
go [[-jumpto] <Object>] [-DisableAliasCD] [-ResetGoHash] [-ResetCDHistory]
get-command cc -syntax
go
get-command cd -syntax
go
```

This seems to make sense. However, I find that IntelliSense works fine for `cc` (i.e. if I type `cc -` and then `Tab` the above 4 Parameters appear, but for `cd` nothing happens.

Is this a bug? Or does this have something to do with declaring the `Set-Alias cd` with the `AllScope` option (which I have to do, the `Set-Alias` does not work without it for the `cd`)

Comment: I've done it for you at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12165 this time, but I encourage you to take a stab at creating one next time - I hope this one can serve as a model.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a run into **a bug, still present as of PowerShell 7.0**:

Most (Windows PowerShell) / a few (PowerShell [Core] 6+) built-in aliases are defined with the `AllScope` option.
(You can discover them with
`powershell -NoProfile { Get-Alias | ? options -like '*AllScope*' }`
/
`pwsh -NoProfile { Get-Alias | ? options -like '*AllScope*' }`).

Redefining *any* alias works correctly in terms of *invocation*.

However, **in terms of *tab completion*, redefined `AllScope` ones malfunction**, as you describe: The *original* alias definition's parameters are still being completed.

```
# Sample function
function foo { param($bar) "[$bar]" }

# Remove the built-in AllScope `cd` alias and redefine it to execute `foo`.
Remove-Item alias:cd; Set-Alias cd foo

# Make sure that the redefinition works:
cd -bar baz # OK: prints '[baz]'

# Try to tab-complete:
cd -b<tab> # NO COMPLETION instead of the expected '-bar'

# Try a parameter from `cd`'s *original* definition, `Set-Location`:
cd -li<tab> # UNEXPECTEDLY EXPANDS TO '-LiteralPath'
```

This problematic behavior has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12165).